# Are the idendifiers of a structured binding initialized in order?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration, initialization, c++17, structured-bindings

It was hard to deduce from the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf).
Will C++17 structured bindings initialize their identifiers from left to right?

Is this guaranteed to print "first", "second", then "third"?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{ A(){std::cout << "first\n";  } };
struct B{ B(){std::cout << "second\n"; } };
struct C{ C(){std::cout << "third\n";  } };

struct D{
  A first;
  B second;
  C third;
};

auto f(){
  return D{};
}

int main (){
  auto [a,b,c] = f();
}
```

Comment: After reading the proposal (a nice and welcome one) I would say it's not only "hard to deduce" but *impossible*. While the proposal shows some examples, it doesn't explicitly say anything about evaluation order or sequencing.

Comment: I think C++ already defines the objects initialization sequence in a class, which is by the declaration order, is it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Right.  I'm hoping its clear from the grammar additions:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0217r2.html

Comment: Reading P0217R2 (Proposed wording for structured bindings) it seems that the output you expect will be printed, but only as part of the object construction ([as answered by Mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38048357/440558)). The initialization of the variables `a`, `b` and `c` will be done by copy-initialization which is done by the copy constructor, and since you have none nothing will be printed for that. However, the order of initialization is not explicitly specified, only the order of variable "introduction".

Comment: Btw, still hoping for a better syntax where I can (but don't have to) define the types of a, b, c manually...

Answer (score 3):

Structured binding does not *copy* values; it *references* them. In your example, `a` is not a copy of the return value's first member; it is a reference to it. Since you're initializing references instead of values, the order of initialization cannot be detected by seeing the order of the constructor calls.

For a struct with public members, the order of fetching those references is irrelevant, since you cannot interfere with that process. For a user-defined struct that implements the methods that structured binding uses, that's a different story.

However, at present, the final standards wording that was voted into the C++17 CD is not available to us. So it is impossible to know what order such interface functions will be called in, or whether it specifies an order at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is guaranteed to print "first", "second", then "third", but not by the `Structured bindings`, instead, by the constructor of `struct D`.

The call to `f()` will construct an instance of `struct D`, and `D`'s constructor will be called, and the objects in `D` will be initialized by the order of declaration, which means `A`, `B`, `C` will be initialized with the order, and "first", "second", "third" is printed.

But I'm not sure how `Structured bindings`'s initialize order is defined.